# Network access was interrupted

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, database-connection, server

The Access database just needs to be open and it will usually crash within the next 20-40mins, resulting in the following error message:

```
Your network access was interrupted. To continue, close the database, and then open it again.
```

More details:

- The database is split, with the back end and front end on a server. The computers are then connected to the server via LAN (ethernet).
- Although there are multiple computers connected to the server, the database only has one user at a time.
- The database has been fine for almost a year, until this week where this error has started occurring.
- We never have connectivity issues with the server.

I have seen several answers saying it is:

- the databases fault, as it is starting to corrupt
- the servers fault, as it broken, dropping my connection briefly
- microsofts fault, they should patch it

I am hoping this is a problem with the database itself, as I am not responsible for the server.

**Does anyone have a definitive solution?**

Comment: We don't have a definitive solution because there are a multitude of factors that come into play, which you have listed in your question. The reason there is ambiguity and different options is because they are *all possible*.

Comment: Is there anymore information I can give you to help narrow it down?

Comment: Well, for one, has anyone experienced any network interference/disconnections?

Comment: Nope, the network runs fine. Usually just used for file sharing between the computers in the office, but have never encountered a connectivity problem.

Comment: *"The database is split, with the ... front end on a server."* - Do you have more than one concurrent user opening the same copy of the front-end .accdb/.mdb file? If so, that can cause problems. For a multi-user Access application, every user **must** have their own copy of the front-end database file on their local hard drive.

Comment: 'every user must have their own copy of the front-end database file on their local hard drive' I did not know that, I will look into it. But currently this system can only be used by one user, because of those problems. I am testing it now with just one user (me) accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem sounds like an unstable LAN connection OR changes the LAN location (e.g. new hardware or changs to admin settings) causing increased latency.

If you have forms in the FE bound to BE tables the latency can cause the connection to be severed resulting in the error you see.

I'm not a network admin but the main culprits I've seen are:

- Users connecting to the network using a VPN using an unstable connection (cell phones, crappy wifi, or just bad ISP service).
- Network admins capping persistent connections to a share causing disconnects.
- Unstable network hardware or bad hardware configuration.
- "Switching" between wired and wireless LAN connections.

I don't think the issue is the database other than having bound forms to a BE database which is more of a fundemental design problem than anything else.

Good luck!

Comment: Yep, your were right.
It turned out to be a dodgy connection to the server, which the network admin sorted :)

Answer (score 2):

I have recently experienced the same problem, and it all started when I moved my DB in an extrernal disk. The same db was working just fine in the local disk, or in the previous external disk. So, i am guessing is just a bug that has to do with the disk letter changing or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I use Access 2010. I had the same issue but solved it in the following ways.

1. On the external data ribbon, go to the Import & link group and click on Linked Table Manager.
2. Click on select all.
3. Click on Ok to refresh the links.

In cases where the path of the BackEnd database file has been changed, browse to the new location and select the new path. This will also refresh the links. This will solve the problem. It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote, "The database has been fine for almost a year, until this week where this error has started occurring."

Clearly something has recently changed for this to be happening and without narrowing the field of possibilities it's anyone's guess.  However, in my experience Jet DB crashes when two or more users are accessing and editing the same record(s) at the same time.  So, if you've recently added new users this is a possibility.

Note: Jet is a file-server DB not a client server, which means the app was probably designed for a specific number of front-end users.  Without knowing more I would start there.

Comment: I have experienced a lot of issues with concurrency but I am sure this has nothing to do with that, as I am testing it with just one user. But yes, something I have done recently, must have broken it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue on this when I figured out that I had a offline directory setup and the sync was having an issue I turned off the sync and tested it and the error went away.